# Apply different aggregate function to a PySpark groupby

Tags: pyspark, geospatial

I have a dataframe with a structure similar to

```
+----+-----+-------+------+------+------+
| cod| name|sum_vol|  date|   lat|   lon|
+----+-----+-------+------+------+------+
|aggc|23124|     37|201610|-15.42|-32.11|
|aggc|23124|     19|201611|-15.42|-32.11|
| abc|  231|     22|201610|-26.42|-43.11|
| abc|  231|     22|201611|-26.42|-43.11|
| ttx|  231|     10|201610|-22.42|-46.11|
| ttx|  231|     10|201611|-22.42|-46.11|
| tty|  231|     25|201610|-25.42|-42.11|
| tty|  231|     45|201611|-25.42|-42.11|
|xptx|  124|     62|201611|-26.43|-43.21|
|xptx|  124|    260|201610|-26.43|-43.21|
|xptx|23124|     50|201610|-26.43|-43.21|
|xptx|23124|     50|201611|-26.43|-43.21|
+----+-----+-------+------+------+------+
```

and now I want to aggregate the `lat` and `lon` values, but using my own function:

```
def get_centroid(lat, lon):
    # ...do whatever I need here
    return t_lat, t_lon
get_c = udf(lambda x, y: get_centroid(x,y), FloatType())

gg = df.groupby('cod', 'name').agg(get_c('lat', 'lon'))
```

but I get the following error:

```
u"expression 'pythonUDF' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;"
```

Is there a way to get the elements of the group by and operate on them, without having to use a UDAF? Something similar to `pandas`

```
df.groupby(['cod','name'])[['lat', 'lon']].apply(f).to_frame().reset_index()
```

Comment: So let´s say that I´m not looking into doing a UDAF. Is there another way? Right now the best way that I found is to convert to a Pandas dataframe and work there...